# Using widget written in Tkinter with pygtk

Tags: sockets, pygtk, widget

I'm trying to attach a Tkinter widget to a pygtk application and I've looked into some ways of doing this.  First there was gtk.Plug and gtk.Socket, but I wasn't able to find any examples outside of the pygtk tutorial..  Then there was python-bonobo, which turns out to be largely deprecated.  Then dbus.

Does anybody know of the most recent way to handle embedding widgets into pygtk? Is it dbus, or something else?  What is the best way to add a foreign widget to a pygtk app?

Thanks for any help, I'm having some trouble moving forward with this...

EDIT: I just ported the widget to pygtk.  Much simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is amazing how little information there is about this, probably because most people just build with one GUI toolkit. However, I did find [this](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t345169-embedding-a-tkinter-widget-inside-a-pygtk-hmi.html)...

It never appears to have been confirmed, but there is a listing for it in the [documentation](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gdkwindow.html#function-gdk--window-foreign-new).

Not sure if this will help, but I hope it does.

Comment: Thanks for this, I wasn't aware of window_foreign_new being in the docs.  I just found some info that Tkinter doesn't support XEMBED protocol, which means that it can't be actually be used for gtk.Plug/gtk.Socket...I don't know if that is true (I found just one instance).

Comment: Does anybody have any further experience with attaching a Tkinter widget to a pygtk application?  Hopefully...